singularity failing due to error squashfs filesystem seems not enabled
Singularity version 4.1.4-1 and squashfs-tools version 4.3 are installed on RHEL 7.9 (Maipo).
Running a container fails with the following message:
(base) -bash-4.2$ singularity --verbose shell myimage.sif
...
VERBOSE: Default mount: /proc:/proc
VERBOSE: Default mount: /sys:/sys
VERBOSE: Default mount: /dev:/dev
VERBOSE: Found 'bind path' = /etc/localtime, /etc/localtime
VERBOSE: Found 'bind path' = /etc/hosts, /etc/hosts
VERBOSE: Default mount: /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
FATAL:   container creation failed: mount /proc/self/fd/9->/var/lib/singularity/mnt/session/rootfs error: while mounting image /proc/self/fd/9: squashfs filesystem seems not enabled and/or supported by your kernel


squashfs is installed and the command mksquashfs is available in /usr/sbin
(base) -bash-4.2$ sudo ls -l /usr/sbin/mksquashfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 130488 Mar  5  2015 /usr/sbin/mksquashfs

How can I enable squashfs?

Edit the /etc/modprobe.d/CIS.conf file and comment out the 'install squashfs /bin/true' line

#install squashfs /bin/true

Enable the squashfs module

modprobe -v squashfs

Verify that the module was enabled

lsmod | grep squashfs

You should see a line starting with "squashfs". Now run singularity.
